# Iterating Over Objects Swift - Array out of Index - AlamofireObjectMapper in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

Using Xcode 7.1

I am trying to make a request to following [JSON](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/f583be1121dbc5e9b0381b3017718a70c31054f7/sample_json) and show it in a tableView

I am using [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) to convert JSON to objects.

**ISSUE:** I don't know how to Iterate over objects in tableView

Below are the custom classes, Alamofire Request & TableView

**Classes**

```
class WeatherResponse: Mappable {
var location: String?
var threeDayForecast: [Forecast]?

required init?(_ map: Map){}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    location <- map["location"]
    threeDayForecast <- map["three_day_forecast"]
 }
}

class Forecast: Mappable {
var day: String?
var temperature: Int?
var conditions: String?

required init?(_ map: Map){}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    day <- map["day"]
    temperature <- map["temperature"]
    conditions <- map["conditions"]
 }
}
```

Alamofire Request

```
//Defined within ViewController
var location: String?
var arrayOfForecasts = [Forecast]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseObject{(response :WeatherResponse?, error: ErrorType?)in
       let location1 = response?.location
        self.location = location1

    let threeDayForecast1 = response?.threeDayForecast
        self.arrayOfForecasts = threeDayForecast1!
        print(threeDayForecast1)
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    } }
```

When I do 'print(threeDayForecast1)' I get the following output:
[MyAppName.Forecast, MyAppName.Forecast, MyAppName.Forecast]

**TableView Protocol**

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let threeDayObj1 = arrayOfForecasts[indexPath.row]
    cell.tempLabel?.text = threeDayObj1.conditions

    return cell
}
```

I get the error that:

```
threeDayObj1 is array out of index
```

Comment: Where you got the error? threeDayObj1 is threeDay?

Comment: sorry there was a typo in the question..I have corrected it..the error is in the line threeDayObj1 = arrayOfForecasts[indexPath.row]

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of AlamofireObjectMapper, with Swift 3, Xcode 8 and iOS 10, you need to do the get call as the followed:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate().responseObject { (response: DataResponse< WeatherResponse>) in
...
```